# What is the process for removing testing and draft apps from the Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play-console, razorpay-andoid-sdk

Any body know how to remove testing and draft Apps from the google play console. Please look at this image and let me know, Thanks
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnEzQ.png)

I am expecting to remove testing and draft Apps from the google play console.